# video_thumbnail with loop(for) method and that keep request to server it must be just once how can i fix?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-thumbnails

```
   enum LoadingStatus { completed, searching, empty }

class ItemListViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  //초기에 로딩 데이터 없음
  LoadingStatus loadingStatus = LoadingStatus.empty; // 상태 비어있음으로 초기화

  List<ItemViewModel> itemList = <ItemViewModel>[]; // NewsArticleViewModel 은 jpa에서 domain이 아닌 request 혹은 response 를 위한 dto 같은 개념이다

  //기사 가져오기
  void getItemList(String url, Map searchType) async {
    //기사 가져오고 현재 상태 로딩중으로 변경
    List<Item> items = await ItemService().`fetchItemList`(url, searchType); // this is the problem code
    loadingStatus = LoadingStatus.searching; // 상태를 searching 으로 바꿔줌
    notifyListeners(); // View단에서  topHeadLines 를 initState를 통해 호출하면 첫째로 api를 불러오고 상태를 현재 검색증으로 바꾼후 이 상태를 Provider에 알려준다
    this.itemList = items // 받아온 데이터를 map으로 바꾼후
        .map((item) => ItemViewModel(item: item)).cast<ItemViewModel>() // 만들어둔 NewsArticleViewModel의 생성자를 통해 객체로 변환시켜준다 여기서 item은 받아온 newsArticles 이다.
        .toList();  // toList를통해 리스트로 만들어준다


    //가져온 데이터가 비어있으면 빈 상태 아니면 성공 상태
    this.loadingStatus =
    this.itemList.isEmpty ? LoadingStatus.empty : LoadingStatus.completed; // 받아온 데이터가 비어있으면 loadingStatus를 비어있음 혹은 완료로 바꾸어준다
    notifyListeners();
  }
}



class ItemService {
  var dio = Dio();

  Future<List<Item>> **fetchItemList**(String url, Map searchType) async {
    print(url);
    final response = await dio.request(
      url,
      data: searchType,
      options: Options(method:'POST'),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = response.data;
      List<dynamic> list = result['data']['content'];
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i ++) {
       await `getThumbnail`(Uri.decodeComponent(list[i]['sampleFile'])).then((res) async { // this is the problem code
          list[i]['img'] = File(res!);
        });
      }
      return list.map((item) => Item.fromJson(item)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception("failed to get top news");
    }
  }

  Future<String?> `getThumbnail` (String sampleFile) async { // this is the problem code
    final thumbnail = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
      video: sampleFile,
      thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
      imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
      maxWidth: 0,
      quality: 1,
    );
    return thumbnail;
  }
}
```

this is what i used in pubspec.yaml
**video_thumbnail: ^0.5.0**

I did build run without loop method and it work but with for it never stops

Answer (score 0):

well...
you can just change this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i ++) {
```

to this one

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {}
```

I believe tho, that you don't need a for cycle in there :)

Comment: but i alreadt check the list.length 
it was 12 
i think its not about for
i guess it from life cycle in flutter (Provider Notifier)

Comment: yourlist[index]

You might need to use this in order to build multiple items with different values from those lists.